# How to get the lastest product from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component to render only the latest product gets from API:

```
const about = ({products}) => {
    const data = products.attributes
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data.Name}</h1>
            <p>{data.Description}</p>
            <p>{Number(data.Price).toLocaleString('it-IT', {style : 'currency', currency : 'VND'})}</p>
            <p>{data.Release}</p>
            <p>{data.Expire}</p>
            <p>{data.Close ? "Close" : "Open"}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const data = await fetch(myAPI)
    const res = await data.json()
    const products = res.data[0]
    return {
        props: {products}
    }
}

export default about;
```

The JSON from API looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "Name": "Vĩ Hoạ",
        "Description": "Vĩ Hoạ",
        "Price": "30000",
        "Release": "2022-05-04",
        "Expire": "2022-05-26",
        "Close": false,
        "createdAt": "2022-05-09T22:28:09.622Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-10T05:50:38.430Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-05-10T05:50:12.353Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 1
    }
  }
}
```

The highest id from JSON is the latest product, I haven't figured out how to resolve this JSON for getting the latest product.`const products = res.data[x]` is used to get the specific product based on x, like an index. This is my temporary solution but not flexible to get the latest one!

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the problem is.  You just want to get the element from `res.data` with the largest `id` value?  You could perhaps sort the array and then grab the first (or last, depending on how you sort) element.  Or perhaps loop over the array and read each element, keeping track of the one with the largest `id` value in a variable.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is descending data by createdAt when getting data from the API. Otherwise, you can use this method.

```
const about = ({products}) => {
    const data = products.attributes
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data.Name}</h1>
            <p>{data.Description}</p>
            <p>{Number(data.Price).toLocaleString('it-IT', {style : 'currency', currency : 'VND'})}</p>
            <p>{data.Release}</p>
            <p>{data.Expire}</p>
            <p>{data.Close ? "Close" : "Open"}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const data = await fetch(myAPI)
    const res = await data.json()
    const products = res.data.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)[0]
    return {
        props: {products}
    }
}

export default about;
```